# How many buffers does DWM have?

Tags: dwm

When DWM is turned on, applications have back buffers and when something in the buffer changes, the DWN need to compose the desktop screen again out of these buffers. Does that mean the DWM have their own back buffer that is used for this composition job before swapping it with the front buffer?

Does that mean applications like video players are, in effect, writing their screen twice, once to the back buffer of the window and the other that is copied from the back buffer of the window to the back buffer of the DWM?

Isn't that much inefficient than when compared to the pre-DWM days?

Comment: (a)Yes. (b)In some instances. (c) In terms of what? - The desktop is a directX surface. IIRC, GDI data must have two of the colour channels swapped to be compatible with the DirectX surface. Many video players use directX for output. This eliminates the need for the application to draw its screen before being converted to BGRA (from RGBA) format and copied to the surface. MSDN actually has a page that deals with the DWM and media presentation, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969539(v=vs.85).aspx